# Algorithm for calculating distance/similarity between sets(!) of colors

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing, cbir

I would like to compare two images based on a color distribution. I've implemented an algorithm (based on kNN) that extracts 3 most dominant colors from an image, together with weights for each color. For example an output of the algorithm would look like:

[(0x00fd8e, 0.1), (0x3ff42e, 0.4),(0x48b2ef, 0.5)]

This is a set. There are three colors, each with it's own weight, which is actually a percentage [0-1] of how much it appears in an image.

What is the best way to calculate a distance/similarity between two of such sets, while taking both colors and weights into account?

I tried to convert the colors into a histogram, and do a chi-square and Bhattacharyya distance.
I also tried to convert a (color,weight) into a vector by multiplying the r/g/b or h/s/v intensities with weights, normalizing them, then adding all three vectors in a set together to get one vector for each set and then comparing those vectors with Euclidean distance.

But non of these thing really worked as they should. When I compared an image with say 100 others and ranked them by similarity, they didn't appear to rank well.

Comment: "color distributions" can be considered "histograms" or "clusterings". for 3 color channels, you have 3 dimensions. histograms are special clusterings according to a fixed "dictionary". a normal clustering's centroids are sensitive to the data itself. -- local feature descriptors instead of colors? -- you're looking for metrics of similarity or dissimilarity. Earth Mover's Distance (EMD) is one such metric, applicable to histograms. there's also a "signature matching distance" (SMD), applicable to clusterings. or do a trivial euclidean distance of the histogram vectors. or cosine similarity.

Comment: in terms of color similarity; if you care about the human perceived similarity between colors then you should use one of the CIE color distance formulas (there are python modules for most of these if you look for them) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: Don't use HSV to compute distances. It's a shitty color space designed for selecting a color in a UI, not for doing any form of color analysis. And the H channel is an angle, which makes distance computation harder (needs special treatment). Linear RGB is OK for general distances, CIELab is better if you want to relate it to human perception of color.